# Using AppCompat Styles

Tags: android, android-styles

If my overarching style for my app has parent "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", will it look the same on any version of Android? For reference, I'm support Android 4.4 and higher.

Comment: That is the point of AppCompatv7, supports API 7 to 22+.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. This is the reason why AppCompat library was created. There you have some more official info what was added: [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)